# How to calculate complex logarithm over non usual branches

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to calculate $log$ (3 -3$i$) over the branches [0,$2$ $\pi$) , [-$\pi$, $\pi$) and [-$\pi$/2 ,3$\pi$/2)

I have no trouble  for [0,$2$ $\pi$) , [-$\pi$, $\pi$) since we have that |3-3i|= $\sqrt{18}$ , so for [-$\pi$, $\pi$)  arctg (-3/3) =$\pi$/4 then log(3+3i) =$\sqrt{18}$ + i $\pi$/4

Also for [0,$2$ $\pi$)  I know that the arg(3+3i)=7$\pi$/4 since the argument in this branch is the angle form the origin to the position of $z$ in counterclockwise motion.

But for [-$\pi$/2 ,3$\pi$/2) I dont really now what to do , I used to think that for get the argument of $z$ in this branch we need only to add 3$\pi$/2 to the argument of this number in the principal branch  but I know this is wrong since we can only need add multiples of $2$ $\pi$ , still I dont get it

Can anyone help me to calculate the logaritm  of this number in this branch  and also explain me the background of calculating complex logarithm over non usual branches like this. Thanks

Comment: If we are on the branch for which $-\pi/2\le \theta<3\pi/2$, what is the argument of $3-3i$?

Comment: Yes, that is what im looking for

Comment: I just recently look at your answer and I found it really helpful bro.  Thanks

Comment: I will be posting some questions  about  some problems I didnt get rightin some past homeworks in compllex analysis this days since Im preparing a test . It would be great to have your help with some of the next questions

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And I am happy to help going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not hard. To compute $\log z$, just write $z$ as $re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is chosen appropriately for the branch you want; then the value is $\log z = \ln r + i\theta$, where "$\ln$" is the ordinary real-valued logarithm of a positive argument.

The "branch" corresponds to a half-open interval of length $2\pi$ so there is a unique $\theta$ in this interval for every nonzero complex number $z$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $3-3i=3\sqrt{2}e^{i(-\pi/4+2n\pi)}$. So, in general, we have

$$\log(3-3i)=\log(3\sqrt{2})+i(-\pi/4+2n\pi)$$

Therefore, the argument $\phi$ of the log is the multi-valued $\phi=-\pi/4+2n\pi$.

If $0\le \phi<2\pi$, then we are on the branch for which $n=1$. There we have

$$\log(3-3i)=\log(3\sqrt{2})+7\pi/4$$

If $-\pi\le \phi<\pi$, then we are on the branch for which $n=0$.  There, we have

$$\log(3-3i)=\log(3\sqrt{2})-\pi/4$$

And if $-\pi/2\le \phi <3\pi/2$, then we are on the branch for which $n=0$.  There, we have

$$\log(3-3i)=\log(3\sqrt{2})-\pi/4$$

Comment: I realize I still dont get how you are aware if the branch is n= 0 or n=1 (or different) ?  :P Specially , in last case [-pi/2 , 3pi/2)

Comment: @Matt Just find the $n$ such that $\phi$ falls within the allowed range.

Comment: Think I got it :in the case [-pi/2 , 3pi/2)  n= 0 because 3pi/2 is congruent to pi module 0   but it is not congruent to  2pi module 1  right ? @Dr. MV

Comment: It is $n=0$ since $-\pi/4\in[-\pi/2,3\pi/2)$.

Comment: Sorry for answer you until know mate. Your answer was more than clear with the last comments you did. I really apreciate your help. I will be asking more complex analysis questions in the next months. :)

Comment: There are uncountably many branches.

Comment: @cloudscape What is the thrust of this comment.  Surely the integers are countable.

Comment: You don't have to split up the circle at integer values. Of course, there are integer many values for a single logarithm, but you can pick an arbitrary interval of length $2\pi$ and define your logarithm for it.

Comment: @cloudscape I don't understand your first sentence.  For the second one, I chose one branch.  What do you not understand?

Comment: See the above answer; you may choose your interval arbitrarily, it doesn't have to start at $2\pi n$. It may also be $[e, e + 2\pi)$, ...

Comment: @Cloudscape Where did I state in my answer that the choice of branch cut was unique.  Nowhere!  In fact, the cut need not even be a linear path.  So, what are you talking about??

Comment: 'the branch for which n=0' (it is, of course only a minor inaccuracy, which is why I just upvoted your answer).

Comment: @Cloudscape Thank you for the up vote.  Much appreciative.  Just to clarify, the quote "the branch for which $n=0$," should be taken in the context of the preceding ones in which the argument of the logarithm were chosen.  Note the statement, "If $0\le \phi<2\pi$.  The "If" is the key word.

Comment: I would be highly appreciative also of a clarifying edit.

Comment: @Cloudscape    The argument $\phi$ of $\log (3-3i)$ is $\phi =-\pi/4+2n\pi$ for all integer $n$.  Once a branch cut is chosen for the $\log$ function, then there exists an integer $n$ such that $\phi$ falls within the $2\pi$ interval defined by the chosen branch cut.  Does that help?

Comment: I do not misunderstand the question. But if you write about 'THE' branch of the logarithm for which n=0, this suggests that there is exactly one branch of the logarithm which attains the given value for the input chosen.